# siunitx table alignment

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, siunitx

I want to align both the numbers and the text to the left using siunitx' S column type. I tried:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{babel}    
\usepackage[locale=DE]{siunitx}    
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty}
\sisetup{multi-part-units=single}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{ngerman}    

\begin{tabular}{l*{2}{S[table-figures-decimal=1,
                        table-text-alignment=left,
                        table-number-alignment=left,
                        table-figures-uncertainty=1]}}
   \toprule
   A & {Column1 symbol $\Delta$} & {Column2 symbol $\delta$} \\
     & {Column1} & {Column2} \\
   \midrule
   B &  -5.0 \pm 1.0 & -10.0 \pm 2.0 \\
   C &   0.0 \pm 1.0 &   5.0 \pm 2.0 \\
   D & -20.0 \pm 1.0 & -100.0 \pm 2.0 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately the text and the minus' from the numbers are not in line. Aligning both to the right works fine.

Comment: You are not really giving the package enough info about your input. Does for example `table-format = -2.1(1)` help?

Comment: `table-format = -2.1(1)` works for column 2 where the numbers have two integer digits. Hence, I have to specify the format individually for each column if the number of integer digits divers. Would be nice to finally set the alignment using one general option.

Comment: Without pre-parsing all of the column content, it's not possible to know in advance how much space to allow for the content of a column. That's the reason that `siunitx` needs the information 'up front': parsing tables would require a massive change to underlying structures and is far too risking in LaTeX2e.

Answer (score 3):

Without pre-parsing all of the column content, it's not possible to know in advance how much space to allow for the content of a column. That's the reason that `siunitx` needs the information 'up front': parsing tables would require a massive change to underlying structures. As such, this is not implemented in `siunitx` and there are no plans to do so. (A 'pure' LaTeX3 table module might be different, but even then for a typesetting application you should either know in advance what the width is or have the data in some form that can be pre-processed, such as a `.csv` file.)